# Apply class only if the date is today with *ngIf

Tags: javascript, html, angular, date, typescript

This is what I've tried.

HTML:

```
<span *ngIf="!today" class="not-today">{{operation}}</span>
<span *ngIf="today" class="today">{{operation}}</span>
```

Component:

```
 private today: any;
 this.today = new Date().getTime();
```

I need to apply the `span.today` class only if it is today (`.not-today` to the spans that are not 'today') and this way I'm getting all spans with `.not-today` class. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: you aren't comparing `today` to anything ... your logic is same as doing `if(1492439523893)` which is always true

Comment: It is always today :) Seriously now - what needs to be equal to today? If you only check if(today) - this will always return true.

Comment: Oh yes.. you are right...

Comment: Thanks guys, but what should I match today with? I need entire range of today, from 00:00, do 23:59..

Comment: Don't write `private today: any;
 this.today = new Date().getTime();` write `today = new Date().getTime();` instead. That way your code is well typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Assuming your `operation` variable is an object and that object has a
>   property of type time and depending on what that time is relevant to
>   the present time you want to assign specific classes to your span
>   element.

There are two ways you can do this:

### ngClass

One is to utilize the `ngClass` attribute by having a method return the relevant class, i.e:

```
getClassFromDate(date: Date) {

   let match = date.getTime(); // convert date to number

   let today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0); // get present day as number
   let day = (n) => today + (86400000 * n); // assuming all days are 86400000 milliseconds, then add or remove days from today

   if (match >= day(1) && match < day(2))
      return 'tomorrow';
   else if (match >= today && match < day(1))
      return 'today';
   else if (match < today && match > day(-2))
      return 'yesterday';
   else
      return 'other';

}
```

And then in your template:

```
<span [ngClass]="getClassFromDate(operation.date)">{{operation.text}}</span>
```

Then of course include the relevant classes in your stylesheet:

```
.tomorrow {...}
.today {...}
.yesterday {...}
.other {...}
```

### class.className

Your classes can also be appended like this:

```
<span [class.tomorrow]="tomorrow" [class.today]="today" [class.yesterday]="yesterday" [class.other]="!tomorrow && !today && !yesterday">{{operation}}</span>
```

In this case it takes a `boolean` and applies the class if the expression equates to true. Note however that you need to rewrite your logic for how the dates are handled.

---

You can read more about the difference between the two [here](https://alligator.io/angular/class-binding-ngclass-angular/). As a general rule of thumb, `ngClass` is for when you have several classes that should potentially be added and `class.className` is for when there is only one.

Comment: Thanks, What should I match today with then? How could I achieve this?

Comment: Well as already noted there is always today. Asking if today is today is like asking if an apple is an apple. What I think you mean is how to match a past date with the current date and see if the past date is greater or less than midnight _today_, right?

Comment: Exactly, sorry I wasn't clear... that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: Ok, let us just first ignore there is such a thing as timezones at the moment. First you need to establish what _today_ is, you can do that by getting the present time `let present = new Date()` reset the clock to midnight `let today = present.setHours(0,0,0,0)`, then you can compare that to a past date, let us say `let past = new Date("2016-07-25T14:39:34.527Z").getTime()` to determent `if (past < today)` then the past is definitely not today. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/dtg1zx1k/

Comment: But how would you do it with yesterday, not past? How to get yesterday..

Comment: @eric.dummy Get the current calendar date of the month: `let date = new Date(today).getDate()` then subtract one day from that date `let yesterday = new Date(today).setDate(date - 1)`, now `if (match >= yesterday && match < today)` then its yesterday. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/dtg1zx1k/1/

Comment: please write this as an answer, and I will accept it. Thanks mate! :)

Comment: Not knowing anything about how your implementation looks like this is the best we are going to get. Good luck!

Comment: I'm getting this error: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined

Comment: Fixed it with: (new Date()).getTime()

Comment: Let's make it interesting, with tomorrow, today and yesterday: https://jsfiddle.net/dtg1zx1k/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve in following way

Assume "operation" as string & "todayDate" as current date ((ie) actual scenario today date get from database).

Code look this

**HTML:**

```
<span [ngClass]="(getTodayClass()=== 'today') ? 'today' : 'not-today'">{{operation}}</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
.today {
    background-color:red;
}
.not-today {
    background-color:green;
}
```

**Component:**

```
//declaraion
todayDate: Date;
operation: string;

private sameDays(d1: Date, d2: Date) {
    return d1.getUTCFullYear() == d2.getUTCFullYear() &&
        d1.getUTCMonth() == d2.getUTCMonth() &&
        d1.getUTCDate() == d2.getUTCDate(); //using UTC methods ensures that two equivalent days in different timezones matching
}

getTodayClass() {
    //variable assign
    this.todayDate = new Date; //this date get from database
    this.operation = "Monday";

    //check condition for database time and current time with help of UTC
    if (this.sameDays(this.todayDate, new Date)) {
        return 'today';
    } else {
        return 'not-today';
    }
}
```

Hope this was helpful for your expectation